# FirebaseMessagingService destroyed right after onCreate()

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FirebaseMessagingService to receive silent push notification in my Android app. However, when I start the service by calling startService(), the service is being destroyed right after.

```
    startService(new Intent(this, NotificationsService.class));
```

I added my google-services.json as expected in the app directory. I added the meta-data tags in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

And added the dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

Here's my NotificationsService that extends the FirebaseMessagingService class:

```
public class NotificationsService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "NotificationsService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.wtf(TAG, "onDestroy()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.d(TAG, "NotificationToken:" + token);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG, remoteMessage.toString());
    }
```

I already checked the 2 others topics about the subject but nothing is working for me.
Can you explain why I have this problem pls?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You do not start the service, you should have registered the service in your manifest and Google Play Services handles the service.

Please read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) again